# What program can display PDF tooltips on a Linux system?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfcomment

I am trying to put in some text tooltips in some `tikz` graphic.

I have found an [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/how-to-put-part-of-a-tikz-graphic-into-a-box-to-measure-its-size) using `pdfcomment`, but after I have used `pdflatex` and opened it with Evince, I don't see any tooltips.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Evince is known for having problems with PDF annotations. See [How to annotate PDF files generated by pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16998/5764) Do you have access to a different viewer, perhaps [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) or [Adobe](http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the only linux pdf viewer that can display tooltips is the linux version of Adobe reader.

Comment: I have now installed Adobe Reader in my  gentoo linux distribution and I can confirm that it is working. The name of the package is 'acroread'.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays (2020), there are rather more options for viewing (and adding) PDF annotations for free on Linux. Ones I have used personally include **Chromium**'s PDF viewer, which can display PDF annotations, and **[MuPDF](https://mupdf.com)**, which can also *create* annotations.

Edit: Chromium isn't very good at displaying annotations, and can't display all kinds of annotations, but MuPDF seems much better at it. Also, Adobe Reader is no longer <del>available</del> supported for Linux.

Edit 2: Another option I've tried now is **[Okular](https://okular.kde.org)**, KDE's PDF reader, which is free (of course) and can create annotations. Its graphical user interface is much less minimal than MuPDF's, but it feels sluggish to me and doesn't seem to support as many types of annotations as MuPDF (in particular, I see no option to attach a file to a PDF document).

Comment: This looks like an important update.

Comment: Acrobat Reader can still be installed on Linux, however the most recent version is very old (version 9.5.5 from 2013). See for example https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux. I still have it installed on Ubuntu, and I use it occasionally if a pdf has JavaScript forms or indeed certain types of annotations that other viewers don't display. Fortunately, Evince has gotten better over the years as well, so the old Adobe Reader is not needed very often anymore.